# How do I make custom snippets for Sublime Text 2 that use the same indentation as the current file?

Tags: sublimetext2

Different projects can use different indentation styles (2-4 spaces, tabs) and I want my custom snippets to follow the style of the current file. The built-in Ruby snippets does this but my custom snippets retain the indentation of the snippet. I checked the docs and found the predefined variables:

```
$TM_SOFT_TABS   YES if translate_tabs_to_spaces is true, otherwise NO.
$TM_TAB_SIZE    Spaces per-tab (controlled by the tab_size option).
```

But I can't really see how to make use of those to control which indents to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the tab character for indents in snippet files. Sublime Text will automatically convert them to the correct indentation style for the current file.